# easy way to check if radio button checked

Tags: javascript, radio-button

I know there are a lot of similar questions how to check if a radio button is checked. So i know how to check this with javascript. My problem is: i don't know how to use it right.
Here's my problem:
I get 5 categories with each 5 question. Each question get 4 radio button with *not important* *less important* *more important* and *very important* .
The user MUST chose each one for every question. So how can i check, if every question is answered? I get no idea to make it easy

Here is the code of two questions:

```
<h2>Arbeit</h2>
<p class="title">Sie machen lieber &Uuml;berstunden als zuhause mit jemandem zu essen<span> 
</span>
</p>
<p class="input radio">
    <input type="radio" value="110" name="11" id="110" />
    <label for="110">Nicht Wichtig</label>
    <input type="radio" value="111" name="11" id="111"
    />
    <label for="111">Weniger Wichtig</label>
    <input type="radio" value="112" name="11" id="112"
    />
    <label for="112">Wichtig</label>
    <input type="radio" value="113" name="11" id="113" />
    <label for="113">Sehr Wichtig</label>
</p>
<p class="title">Wenn Sie sich ein Ziel gesetzt haben, erreichen Sie dieses auch<span> Egal was es &quot;kostet&quot;
</span>
</p>
<p class="input radio">
    <input type="radio" value="120" name="12" id="120" />
    <label for="120">Nicht Wichtig</label>
    <input type="radio" value="121" name="12" id="121"
    />
    <label for="121">Weniger Wichtig</label>
    <input type="radio" value="122" name="12" id="122"
    />
    <label for="122">Wichtig</label>
    <input type="radio" value="123" name="12" id="123" />
    <label for="123">Sehr Wichtig</label>
</p>
<p class="title">Sie bringen die Arbeit auch nach hause<span> Sie arbeiten auch von Zuhause aus</span>
</p>
<p class="input radio">
    <input type="radio" value="130" name="13" id="130" />
    <label for="130">Nicht Wichtig</label>
    <input type="radio" value="131" name="13" id="131"
    />
    <label for="131">Weniger Wichtig</label>
    <input type="radio" value="132" name="13" id="132"
    />
    <label for="132">Wichtig</label>
    <input type="radio" value="133" name="13" id="133" />
    <label for="133">Sehr Wichtig</label>
</p>
<p class="title">Sie helfen einem Kollegen, auch wenn Sie dann mit Ihrer Arbeit in R&uuml;ckstand
    geraten<span> 
</span>
</p>
<p class="input radio">
    <input type="radio" value="140" name="14" id="140" />
    <label for="140">Nicht Wichtig</label>
    <input type="radio" value="141" name="14" id="141"
    />
    <label for="141">Weniger Wichtig</label>
    <input type="radio" value="142" name="14" id="142"
    />
    <label for="142">Wichtig</label>
    <input type="radio" value="143" name="14" id="143" />
    <label for="143">Sehr Wichtig</label>
</p>
```

Comment: First things first, each set of radio buttons for a question should share the same `group` attribute so that you may only select one per group.

Comment: ^ They do share the same name...

Comment: @elclanrs: 1 group = 1 name... what is wrong with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since they're radios and only one can be checked per group try the following:

```
var categories = document.querySelectorAll('p.radio'),
    checked = document.querySelectorAll('p.radio input:checked');

if ( checked.length == categories.length ) {
  // every question was answered
} else {
  // some question(s) were not answered
}
```

Comment: +1 though remember that the `:checked` selector does not work in IE8.